# Does pyshp read .prj files properly?

Tags: pyshp

I want to read a shapefile using pyshp:

```
sf = shapefile.Reader(('/tmp/India_PCs_Boundary_4_2_19/India_PCs_Boundary.shp'))
```

but when I look at the result, the polygons look all squishy and distorted; they're supposed to exactly cover India, but they don't.

One theory for what might have happened is that I did not read the .prj file correctly, and the .prj file contained some sort of projection data that would un-distort the polygons.

When I read the pyshp documentation, it says:

> You specify the base filename of the shapefile or the complete filename
>   of any of the shapefile component files....
>   OR any of the other 5+ formats which are potentially part of a shapefile. The
>   library does not care about file extensions.

But it does not mention .prj specifically.

Does pyshp, by default, read .prj files correctly?  If not, is there a way to get it to do so?

Answer (score 2):

PyShp does not handle projections. You can use [pyproj](https://github.com/pyproj4/pyproj) for that. What are you using to visualize the shapefile? If the data is in a geographic coordinate system, it won't appear in the cartesian format that you are expecting.